# ActiveAdmin select filter collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I am trying to create a select category filter in ActiveAdmin(1.0.0pre4) with Rails 4. Every company has different categories. How can I create a filter collection which is based on the current_user's company?

```
filter :by_category,
        as: :select,
        collection: proc { Category.by_company(current_company) }
```

This results in an `undefined method 'map' for #<Proc:0x007fccc3b29340>`

If I remove the surrounding proc than I got the following error when I start the server:

```
undefined local variable or method 'current_company' for #<ActiveAdmin::ResourceDSL:0x007fb8a8c332b0> (NameError)
```

Is it possible to do this with ActiveAdmin 1.0.0pre4?

Answer (score 2):

Can you get the `current_company` from the `current_user` ? ie `current_user.company`

If so,

```
filter :by_category,
    as: :select,
    collection: proc { Category.by_company(current_user.company) }
```

Comment: undefined local variable or method `current_user'. But I got this error right after starting the server, so there is no current_user then, because there are no requests yet. That's why i wanted to use lambdas or procs but those raise errors as well.

Comment: What version of ActiveAdmin are you using? I am able to start my server and filter as expected with `gem 'activeadmin', '1.0.0.pre4'`.  If updating your version doesn't work, please share your entire file.